# Python logging not recording debug messages

Tags: python, logging

I have created a package and I'm adding logging file to log debug information, here is my `__init__.py` file:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='logs/tmp.log',
                  format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s :: %(message)s',
                  level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('logs/tmp.log')
logger.debug('First debug!')
```

When I ran the code, the file `logs/tmp.log` wasn't even created, so I created the file manually just in case `logging` needs the file to exists, but it's not working either, any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try  `logger = logging.getLogger()` and then logger.debug('First debug')

Comment: If I print that logger I get `<RootLogger root (INFO)>`, and with my code `<Logger logs/tmp.log (INFO)>`. In none of both it prints anything in my log file.